# Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library?

Tags: typescript

I am encountering an error when trying to use `Object.entries()` in my TypeScript project, even though my `tsconfig.json` file seems to be correctly configured.

Here is the piece of code causing the error:

```js
const getEntries = <T, K extends keyof T>(data: T) =>
    Object.entries(data) as [keyof T, T[K]][];
```

And here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2019",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "outDir": "out",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2019"
        ]
    }
}
```

The error message I receive is:

```
error TS2550: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does that error occur when you run `tsc`? Or is it the editor giving the error?

Comment: Yes after i run the tsc filename.ts

Comment: Same problem here, targeting es2022. Compiles successfully